# pg_restore on OS X

Tags: pg-dump, pg-restore

I'm running this command to export a database:

```
sudo PGUSER="postgres" PGPASSWORD="D" /Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/pgAdmin3.app/Contents/SharedSupport/pg_dump --format=c okay_db_3 > '/Volumes/1TB/databasebackutest.backup'
```

And it works fine no error.

But I don't know how to restore.
So far I've tried:

```
PGUSER="postgres" PGPASSWORD="D" /Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/pgAdmin3.app/Contents/SharedSupport/pg_restore -F c -v -U postgres -d okay_db3recover1 /Volumes/1TB/databasebackutest.backup
```

and

```
sudo PGUSER="postgres" PGPASSWORD="D" /Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/pgAdmin3.app/Contents/SharedSupport/pg_restore --dbname=okay_db_mac /Volumes/1TB/databasebackutest.backup
```

but no luck.
I'm getting

> [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 3847; 2606 41233 CONSTRAINT
>   Sm2SequenceContainer_Sm2TiTrack_pkey postgres

when I try to report the database back